# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Asynchronous processing not supported on Servlet 2.x container

Tags: jsp, asynchronous, servlets, jersey, servlet-3.0

I couldn't run Async process in Glassfish Jersey. It throws the following error. i tried every solution found in internet but still facing the same problem. Here are my files

OUTPUT:

Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Asynchronous processing not supported on Servlet 2.x container.

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.yyy.xxx</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <multipart-config>
            <!-- 100MB max -->
            <max-file-size>104857600</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>104857600</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.yyy.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.27</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.11.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.27</jersey.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

How to upgrade servlet 2.X to 3.X??

Comment: You can't just upgrade container versions. Whatever container version is implemented in the server, that's what you're limited it. I'm not sure which Glassfish version started using Servlet 3.0. I think maybe Glassfish 4. Or maybe 3, I don't know, I never used 3. But from the error, it looks like your Glassfish version is an older one that still used Servlet 2.x

Comment: I'm using the latest version